# May I remove a phone/email call/sent/recieve histories from android app

Tags: android, history

I'm a android app developer.

I wanna remove a specific phone/email history.

Android 2.2

My friend has a secret girlfriend.
he wanna remove phone/mail history from her automatically.

I'd like to develop history remover for him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to be a good friend, don't write your friend a history remover Android app. Give him a kick in the butt and tell him to make up his mind.

Answer (score -1):

You need to work with the CallLog.Calls class wich contains the recent calls.

More info in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html